# VBA Filter (Searching Interger Value)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code which filters based on what is typed into the textbox. This works for strings however it does not work for integer searches. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
On Error Resume Next
metin = TextBox1.Value
Set bul = Range("a4:a10").Find(What:=metin)
Application.Goto Reference:=Range(bul.Address), Scroll:=False
Selection.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=TextBox1.Value & "*"
If metin = "" Then
  Selection.AutoFilter
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Range("a4:a10").NumberFormat = "@"` at the beginning. With numbers, Excel tries to compare values, not their digit representation as string. Hence, it tries to match exactly :) With that line it will treat digit sequence as string and will apply string comparison. The final code would be:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

Range("a4:a10").NumberFormat = "@"

On Error Resume Next
metin = TextBox1.Value
Set bul = Range("a4:a10").Find(What:=metin)
Application.Goto Reference:=Range(bul.Address), Scroll:=False
Selection.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=TextBox1.Value & "*"
If metin = "" Then
  Selection.AutoFilter
End If
End Sub
```

For optimization sake, you should set the range format somewhere outside this method, so you don't have to do it every time the text box has changed.

Comment: hmm tried exactly what you wrote but it still wont find the numbers in the column returns no results

Comment: I think I understand my mistake but the problem is that it has to be the exact number searched? What I mean is if i want to search for 123 I have to type 123 and not just 12 is there a way to do that?

Comment: Works for me exactly the same as for any other input. So, it does work like you intented.

Comment: When it comes to numbers, the comparison is exact.